# Can we assume for free the upper bound for a variable in the minimization problem $\min_{(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}} t$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

> Problem: Let us consider the following minimization problem
> \begin{align*}
> &\min_{(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}} t\\
> \text{s.t }& \Vert x-q_i\Vert^2 \le r_i^2 + t,\ \forall i =
> \overline{1,k},
> \end{align*}
> where $q_i$ and $r_i$ are known value. Show that the problem admits an optimal value.

**My attempt:** I intend to show that the problem admits a minimizer by using Weierstrass's theorem. To do that, the most important thing is to show the constraint set is bounded. Easily, we can see that $t$ is bounded from below. Now, if $t$ is bounded from above, everything is done (since it yields $x$ is bounded also). So, I wonder if we can assume for free the upper bound of $t$?

Comment: Leaving aside the "for free" part, which is just a wish ("I wish I were done with this"). Since $t$ is manifestly not bounded above, the question is: why could we assume it bounded above at all, possibly with a lot of work?

Comment: Geometrically, the constraints of your problem are just balls centered at $q_i$ with radius $\sqrt{r_i^2 + t}$, and the optimization problem can be interpreted as finding the minimum increase $t$ in the radius of the balls so that all of them intersect. Intuitively, if $q_i$ and $r_i$ are finite, choosing $t$ large enough (e.g., something like $t = \max_{i,j} \| q_i - q_j \|_2$) should make the problem feasible, which means that $t$ is bounded above by that value.